# GitHub Actions - empty env secrets

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, github-actions

I've started playing with GitHub actions, but I'm struggling with accessing repository secrets which I pass as env's.

My workflow file:

```
name: Invite

on: 
  pull_request:
    branches: [master]
    types: [closed]
jobs:
  invite:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Hello world action
        uses: lekterable/inclusive-organization-action@master
        env:
          SECRET_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SECRET_TOKEN }}
          organization: string
          SUPER_SECRET: ${{ secrets.SUPER_SECRET }}
```

action index file

```
const core = require('@actions/core')
const github = require('@actions/github')

const run = async () => {
  try {
    ...
    console.log('env', process.env)
    const token = process.env.SECRET_TOKEN
    const secret = process.env.SUPER_SECRET
    const organization = process.env.organization
    console.log('organization', organization)
    console.log('token?', !!token)
    console.log('secret?', !!secret)
    console.log('token length', token.length)
    ...
  } catch (error) {
    core.setFailed(error.message)
  }
}

run()
```

as you can see I'm passing 3 env's, the organization which has a value of 'string' exists as expected, but SECRET_TOKEN and SUPER_SECRET are empty.

[image]

And yes, I do have the secrets set in the repo which runs the action:

[image]

Is there something that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Here for example: https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/creating-and-using-encrypted-secrets#using-encrypted-secrets-in-a-workflow

Comment: They are talking about forking the repo in which the workflow is defined not about forking a repo of the action. In my case it would be the 'github-actions-test-repo', so if someone forked it, he would not have access to the secrets, which obviously makes sense, but I'm not working on a fork, as it's my repository. Appreciate the trying though, thanks for that ;)

Comment: did you re-run `npm run build` to update your changes? to `./dist/index.js`, ive essentially setup the same and having no issues, https://github.com/lcherone/gh-actions/commit/cb456052747169dbae44d0396def5189d5dd2c0a/checks?check_suite_id=299460424 the secret env var (process.env.foo) won't show its values but it is 10 chars long. I'm thinking now you just have old code in ./dist.

Comment: you were actually right when mentioning the forked repo, I just understood that they meant that when you are opening pull requests IN the forked repo, then action will not get secrets, but actually when you are opening PR FROM the forked repo to the main one, actions still won't have access to them, thanks for your help :)

Comment: I have implemented a workaround documented in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61450807/177275 to solve these types of problems. Essentially an action that runs on PR creates some artifacts, and later a cron job that runs every 5 minutes scans for those artifacts and acts on them. I use it to post build results to the pull request page as comments, but you can adapt the same approach for other use cases.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found a solution, what I did to work around it is instead of running the action on closing the PR I'm running it on a new commit on master, this has to be triggered by someone with 'write rights' to the repo, therefore, it has access to the repo secrets.

It's a bit harder to check if the commit is a merge commit and we have to explicitly fetch more info about the PR, but it works. Source code of an action I was trying to build if someone is interested: https://github.com/lekterable/inclusive-organization-action

Answer (score 22):

In my case I had to pass the secrets to a reusable workflow by adding `secrets: inherit` to the parent job

```
jobs:
  call-workflow-passing-data:
    uses: octo-org/example-repo/.github/workflows/reusable-workflow.yml@main
    with:
      config-path: .github/labeler.yml
    secrets: inherit # <= this one
```

Doc: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#passing-inputs-and-secrets-to-a-reusable-workflow

Answer (score 19):

**Update**

While the original answer below does still apply to *public* repositories, there are a couple of [new updates](https://github.blog/2020-08-03-github-actions-improvements-for-fork-and-pull-request-workflows/) that may help for some use cases.

- If your repository is private, you can now [enable workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/disabling-or-limiting-github-actions-for-a-repository#enabling-workflows-for-private-repository-forks) from forks.
- If your repository is public, there is a new [`pull_request_target`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request_target) event that is not subject to any token restrictions.

**Original Answer**

The reason you are experiencing this behaviour is because the `Invite` workflow is being triggered by a pull request from a forked repository.

> With the exception of GITHUB_TOKEN, secrets are not passed to the runner when a workflow is triggered from a forked repository.

When this happens, the `actor` of the workflow is the user that opened the pull request. If that user doesn't have write access to your repository then they cannot use secrets (other than `GITHUB_TOKEN`).

> Anyone with write access to a repository can create, read, and use secrets.

ref: https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/creating-and-using-encrypted-secrets#using-encrypted-secrets-in-a-workflow

If you run this step in your workflow you will see that it has nothing to do with your action. The `TEST_SECRET` secret won't be available in the workflow either.

```
      - name: Test
        env:
          TEST_GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          TEST_SECRET: ${{ secrets.TEST_SECRET }}
        run: |
          echo ${#TEST_GITHUB_TOKEN}
          echo ${#TEST_SECRET}
```

[image: Test secrets on pull requests from forks]

Checking the event data in the GitHub context you'll see that `actor` is the user that forked the repository and opened the pull request.

```
      - name: Dump GitHub context
        env:
          GITHUB_CONTEXT: ${{ toJson(github) }}
        run: echo "$GITHUB_CONTEXT"
```

[This is a different but related issue](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/Can-t-push-to-forked-repository-on-the-original-repository-s/m-p/35916/highlight/true#M2372) answered by a GitHub staff member where it's explained that these limitations on forked repositories exist to "prevent malicious actors from using actions to poison upstream or downstream repos."

Comment: yup, you are right, I just thought that when talking about forked repo they were speaking about workflows triggered IN the forked repo, I didn't expect that action triggered by a PR merged to the main repository was also the case. Can you think of a way of doing this? I mean I really need in an action triggered by a PR merged to the main repository to have access to the secret

Comment: I’ve run into the same issue but for a slightly different use case. I’ve tried a couple of ways to work around it but unfortunately not found anything that works. Even if I had found a work around I imagine that GitHub would find a way to close it off. It’s basically a privilege escalation security issue. The only way to use secrets is to have an event that is triggered by a user with write access.

Comment: Can  you think un any other scenario where this could happen? I'm working on my own repository and I have this exact problem

Comment: so, is there any workaround to resolve this issue?