# How do I use secrets in Github Actions?

Tags: node.js, github, github-actions

I feel like this is a really stupid question but can't seem to figure it out.  I have [set up a really simple node.js project](https://github.com/sohmc/node-secrets-test) with a `API_KEY` as a secret.

In the [nodejs action yml](https://github.com/sohmc/node-secrets-test/blob/eff347a33e5b2561cbf7831e861fda149e489b8a/.github/workflows/node.js.yml) I have the following:

```
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      env:  
        API_KEY: ${{ secrets.API_KEY }} 
    - run: export 
    - run: npm ci
    - run: npm run build --if-present
    - run: npm test
```

[`API_KEY` doesn't show in `export`](https://github.com/sohmc/node-secrets-test/runs/1211791112?check_suite_focus=true#step:4:4) as I would expect it to nor does it show when I [`console.log(process.env)`](https://github.com/sohmc/node-secrets-test/runs/1211791112?check_suite_focus=true#step:7:5).

[According to the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets), this should work as-is.  I feel like I'm missing something really simple.

This is not a fork as [suggested in this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58737785/github-actions-empty-env-secrets).

What am I missing to get the API_KEY available in my node script?

Comment: Have you added the secret to the repository?

Comment: `export` won't show it because it's not in the same step. You have to set the secret in each step that you want to have access to it.

Comment: @BenjaminW. yes, the secret is in the repository.  Do you have an example of how I should set the secret in each step?

Comment: If you add the `env:` and `API_KEY` fields to the run step? Like `-env:\nAPI_KEY: ${{ secrets.API_KKEY }}\nrun:export`? (Replace `n` with newlines and proper indentation, of course)

Comment: @BenjaminW. that seems to be the answer.  I wonder why the documentation is not clear about this.  I'll create a PR on their actions page to see why this is the case.

Comment: I think it's kind of clear, let me add an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Environment variables can be defined on three levels:

- Globally: a top-level map called [`env`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#env)
- On a per-job level: in [`jobs.<job_id>.env`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idenv)
- On a per-step level: in [`jobs.<job_id>.steps[*].env`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsenv)

The preference is given to the most specific variable available. For example:

```yaml
env:
  VAR: I am global
jobs:
  job1:
    steps:
      - run: echo "$VAR"  # "I am global"
  job2:
    env:
      VAR: I am on the job level
    steps:
      - run: echo "$VAR"  # "I am on the job level"
      - env:
          VAR: I am on the step level
        run: echo "$VAR"  # "I am on the step level"
      - run: echo "$VAR"  # "I am on the job level"
```

To set an environment variable in a step, dynamically, and make it available for further steps, you have to use an [environment file](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#environment-files) (this has [changed in October 2020](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-10-01-github-actions-deprecating-set-env-and-add-path-commands/) from using workflow commands, which are now deprecated for environment variables):

```yaml
steps:
  - name: Set the variable
    run: echo "foo=bar" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
  - name: Print the variable
    run: echo "$foo"  # bar
```

The old, now deprecated way would set it like this:

```yaml
run: echo "::set-env name=foo::bar"
```

but this now triggers a deprecation warning.

Comment: how can I ensure my local build/run can access github secrets from process.env ?